# Usar Clip-path en Css

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando usar `clip-path` en la parte CSS de mi web. Actualmente tengo escrito lo siguiente:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 75%, 0% 50%);
```

y sale como muestro en la figura 1.

Estoy intentando conseguir la figura 2, que es igual pero invertida, pero no lo consigo, lo mas parecido que tengo es:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 50% 0%, 100% 25%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

Lo que me sale esta representado en la Figura 3, siendo la parte azul lo que no se pinta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de que esta fallando?

He comprobado punto por punto y todos están bien situados menos la esquina inferior derecha del rectángulo.

Si escribo:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 50% 0%, 100% 25%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
```

Me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El *inverso* del corte original, en mi opinión, sería:

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 25%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 50%);
```

Esto es haciendo un *espejo*, dónde el espacio que recortas originalmente de la parte de abajo ahora lo recorto en la parte de arriba.

Si quieres mantener la *altura* del recorte y solo invertir la forma, entonces sería:

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
```

Dejo este ejemplo para que puedas verlos aquí mismo, haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div>img {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.nopath {
  clip-path: none;
}

.path1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 75%, 0% 50%);
}

.path2 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 25%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.path3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="noclipped" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/balloon-small.jpg" title="Sin recorte" alt="Ejemplo sin recorte" class="nopath" />
  <img id="clipped1" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/balloon-small.jpg" title="Recorte original" alt="Recorte original" class="path1" />
    <img id="clipped2" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/balloon-small.jpg" title="Espejo" alt="Espejo" class="path2" />
    <img id="clipped3" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/balloon-small.jpg" title="Inverso" alt="Inverso" class="path3" />
</div>
```

Recuerda que el polígono no es más que una secuencia de puntos x,y que se unen por líneas.  Se requiere darle al sistema un polígono cerrado. El sistema dibujará automáticamente una línea entre el primero y el último punto.

El polígono que estás dando forma estas líneas:

[image: Líneas uniendo los puntos del polígono enviado]

Agregar una última línea entre el último punto y el primero, nos daría (la última línea la he puesto en rojo)

[image: Intentando cerrar el polígono]

Nos da una polígono que no tiene sentido, puesto que se entrecortan dos líneas.

Supongo que el sistema detecta esto y entonces, lo que hace, es comenzar a ignorar los último punto, hasta poder cerrar un polígono dónde no se crucen líneas. Eso lo encuentra ignorando el último punto, con lo que traza la línea roja a continuación e ignora los segmentos de los últimos puntos, que ahora he dejado en gris:

[image: Polígono que si se pudo cerrar]

Digo, supongo, viendo la imagen que muestras, es lo que parece que hace.